Unable to trap System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException in .NET code and Breaks IIS
I am unable to trap the error thrown by the XslCompiledTransform class when I try to load a stylsheet with broken or bad Xslt code in it.  This causes and unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception that inevitably crashes in w3wp.exe, despite that I have this bit of code wrapped in a
try { } catch(Exception unhandled) { // serve friendly message here to user }
block.
In my current case, one of my included stylesheets duplicates an existing template function.  Now I realize this is going to break things, but why can't I handle this exception in my C# code?
Here is the exact error that I get when I attach the debugger when w3wp.exe unhandled exception is debugged locally.  I've included a couple of screenshots as well.


System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException
  HResult=0x80131942
  Message='helper.name' is a duplicate template name.
  Source=FLX
  StackTrace:
   at ProjectFlx.FlxTemplater.LoadTransformation(XslCompiledTransform xslt) in D:\GitHub\ProjFlx\Src\TMPLTSite\WebTemplater.cs:line 475
   at ProjectFlx.FlxTemplater.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<ProcessTemplate>b__0() in D:\GitHub\ProjFlx\Src\TMPLTSite\WebTemplater.cs:line 429
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    ProjectFlx.FlxTemplater.LoadTransformation(System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform) in WebTemplater.cs
    ProjectFlx.FlxTemplater.ProcessTemplate.AnonymousMethod__0() in WebTemplater.cs
    [External Code]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/uHzaP.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/bXAPG.png

The calling routine
NOTE: Due to complexity and size of my Xml and Xsl, I need to increase stack size for the transformation.  That is where the anonymous call comes from.
            try
        {
            var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            //xslt = LoadTransformation(xslt);
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => xslt = LoadTransformation(xslt), 8 * 1024 * 1024);
            t.Start();
            t.Join();

            XsltArgumentList xsltparms = DicToXsltParms();
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _xml.Save(mem);
                mem.Flush();
                mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var readersettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                var reader = XmlReader.Create(mem, readersettings);

                using (_writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    xslt.Transform(reader, xsltparms, _writer);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(System.Xml.Xsl.XsltCompileException handled)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Caught XsltCompileException");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(handled.Message);
        }
        //catch(System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException handled)
        //{

        //}
        catch (Exception unhandled)
        {
            var ex = new Exception("Failed to Transform xml/xslt", unhandled);
            ex.Source = "ProjectFlx.FlxTemplater.ProcessTemplate";
            throw ex;
        }


despite that I have this bit of code wrapped in a try { } catch(Exception unhandled) { // serve friendly message here to user } block There is no try catch shown in your example code ?

The try catch wraps the call to LoadTransformation routine. I can share that if it helps.

I know its seems stupid for me to point this out but when you are using a debugger the debugger will stop at the exception. If you "continue" stepping through the code do you go to your error catch block next? Also yes I think it would help to post the calling code where you are catching the error ... I am curious why that is an "anonymous method" in your stack trace too.

OK, so at the point the exception is caught, there is no stepping through, or in, or out.  The code dies here so we never get to the calling routine.  After you click to continue beyond the error, the JIT unhandled exception pops up again and you end up right back at the same exception.  I think what kills the IIS process is this feels like it is stuck in some sort of a Try loop within the XslCompiledTransform class, but I'm not sure.

Do you get that XSLT successfully through xsltc.exe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-compiler-xsltc-exe or does trying that at least give you some hint as to where the problem comes from?

@MartinHonnen I know exactly where the error in XSLT is, so not an issue with that.  The issue is strictly in my code trying to trap this error.  Strange, and I should emphasize, that not all XSLT compile issues breaks my code, just certain things (which I don't fully understand).  In this case, the XSLT issue is a duplicate template name, and this is causing the unhandled exception as described.  Where as, an unclosed Xml tag is handled by code as expected.

@topsail any more ideas regarding the anonymous call?  I'm wondering if perhaps I'm not trapping the exception in code because of the behaviour of multi-threading as I described.

Does it make a difference if you don't create a new thread for the load xslt job? That does stand out as unusual here.

@topsail it does make a difference.  I finally had a chance to test this.  If I remove the threading steps from the process the code properly handles the error.  So the issue is handling an exception that occurs in a separate thread.  Any hints on handling an exception from a separate thread?
